# Correct date is not being reflected on form submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google form that has a dynamic dropdown with 'Dates' as its list. Whenever a user submits a response, it goes to a sheet as a string (For Example: **'5/22/2017** instead of just **5/22/2017**). I have this google script that runs on form submit to remove the single qoute so that it will be considered as a date instead of string .

```
function editDate(e){

var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('RAW');
var rg = sh.getRange(2,6,sh.getLastRow()-1,2);
var data = rg.getValues(); 

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
var datstr=String(data[i][0]).replace("'","");
data[i][0]=new Date(datstr);
}
rg.setValues(data);
}
```

I noticed that when the **single qoute (')** is removed, the date becomes the previous date (For ex. on form submit, the dropdown value is **'5/22/2017**, but when the script runs, it becomes **5/21/2017 9:00:00**. I have created a sample google form and connected it to a test sheet to test out the exact same code and it's working perfectly fine and reflecting the correct date. But on my actual file it's not, any recommendation on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried putting log and checking value of `datstr` and `new Date(datstr)` ?

Comment: I actually did and on the log, it shows the correct date. Though I think I have found a solution to this. I'll put the answer below:)

Comment: The reason the date, time, and datetime Form answers are sent as `String` and not `Date` is exactly because of timezones - Google doesn't know what timezones your question is supposed to use, and instead trusts that you made your question with the appropriate inputs. Additionally, the year is not a required component of a DateItem's answer

Answer (score 2):

So I have edited my script to reflect the correct date and it works perfectly fine now!:)

I have change the line:

```
data[i][0]=new Date(datstr);
```

to this:

```
data[i][0]=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(datstr), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a drop down question with multiple pre-canned dates and they showed up in the Form responses sheet as strings with a '.  I just selected the entire column and formatted it as a date and the ' was removed and some simple tests show that they are being treated correctly as dates.